# Publishing Custom Deserializer to Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: c#, azure, docker, .net-core

I am trying to implement a custom de-serializer on the input to an Azure Stream Analytics Job.  I have started with the Visual Studio 2019 Azure Deserializer project.  It looks like it's a c# class library that creates a .dll that needs to somehow be published to Azure.  However, when I attempt to publish from Visual Studio 2019, I get an error indicating:

> "Docker support must be enabled in the project".

I try to add Docker support by right-clicking on my project and then navigating to "Add".  This is where Docker support can be added for .Net Core projects etc.  However, since this is just a class library, it doesn't seem to allow me to add Docker support.  I have confirmed that if I create a .Net Core project, I can add Docker support.
Since the sample project comes from Microsoft, I would assume that it should be correct as-is.  However, I'm very new to Azure and can't figure out if I could somehow manually upload the .dll to Azure.

Even if I could figure that out, where should it go?
I have Googled for quite a while and the only documents I have come across are the Microsoft documentation pages on how to create the deserializer, but not on how to integrate it into Azure.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code has a Job Config file where you specify the storage container for your custom code. With this configuration running to job locally works.

"CustomCodeStorage": {
"AccountName": "",
"AccountKey": "",
"ContainerName": "",
"Path": "UserCustomCode.zip"
},

What I could not figure out is how to make that configuration available to a real Job as there is no place to configure this in the portal.